# Is there a code that can find on which movieclip I clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I'm making a game in AS3.

I've got a scene with empty space. There are empty space 1, empty space 2...etc

When the player click on an empty space, a usebox appear with 2 buttons. **It the same usebox for all the empty spaces.**
When the player click on the buttons "buy" a windows appears where he can choose between different buildings (same windows for all the empty spaces).

When he clicks on the building that he wants, the function "build" is called (`someBuilding.visible = true`) and the building appears on the scene.

But, I don't how to tell the code to make the building corresponding to the empty space visible..

If the player has clicked on the empty space 2 for example, how can I tell the code to make `someBuilingInEmptySpace2.visible = true`?
If he has clicked on the empty space 3 --> `someBuilingInEmptySpace3.visible = true`?

something like:

```
function build():void{
if clicked on emptyspace2 {
 someBuilingInEmptySpace2.visible = true ; }
if clicked on emptyspace3 {
..
.
```

---

EDIT

Thank you for your answers, but I don't really see where to put it. Here's my code:

I've got **Engine.as** where the elements of the game are:

```
private function createBackground(thisBack:String):void{
for (i in usableItems){
                var thisClip = usableItems[i];
                thisClip.buttonMode = true;
                thisClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, examine, false, 0, true);
                thisClip.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
private function createUI():void{
            
            toolbar = new Toolbar(stage);
            addChild(toolbar);
            toolbar.x = 0;
            toolbar.y = 400;
                        
            buildings = new Buildings(stage);
            addChild(buildings);
            buildings.visible = false;
            
puzzle = new Puzzle(stage);
            
            stage.addEventListener("endGame", endGame, false, 0, true);
        }

private function examine(e:MouseEvent):void{
                stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("itemClicked"));
                    useBox = new UseBox(stage, e.currentTarget);
                    useBox.x = mouseX;
                    useBox.y = mouseY;
                    stage.addChild(useBox);
                }
```

So when the player clicks on an empty space (emptyspace2 for exemple), the function examine is called and the useBox appears.

In my **UseBox.as :**

```
public function UseBox(stageRef:Stage, thisThing:Object){
this.stageRef = stageRef;
this.thisThing = thisThing;
this.visible = true;
            useButton.buttonMode = true;
            lookButton.buttonMode = true;
            lookButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, lookAt, false, 0, true);
            useButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useThing, false, 0, true);

private function useThing(e:MouseEvent):void{
Engine.buildings.visible = true;
        useButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useThing);
            }
```

In my **Buildings.as**

```
public function Batiments(stageRef:Stage){
houseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, houseConstruction, false, 0, true);

}
private function houseConstruction(e:MouseEvent):void{
            var house;
            var emptyspace1;
                    trace("choix");
                stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("itemClicked"));
            Engine.buildings.visible = false;
            Engine.puzzle.houseBuilt();
            toolbar.money.text = String( Number(toolbar.money.text ) - 100 );
                }
```

And, finally, in my **Puzzle.as**

```
public function Puzzle(stageRef:Stage){
allPuzzles = new Object;
allPuzzles.tundra.maisonBought = false;
}

public function maisonBuilt():void{
            var house;
            var emptyspace1;
            for (var i in Engine.usableItems){
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "HOUSE")
                house = Engine.usableItems[i];
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "EMPTYSPACE1")
                emptyspace1= Engine.usableItems[i];
                    }
            allPuzzles.tundra.houseBought = true;
            house.visible = true;
            house.gotoAndStop("contruction");
            house.lookTag = "1";
            timeConstruction.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, constructionFini);
                    timeConstruction.start();
            emptyspace1.visible = false;
}
```

Where should I put the emptyspace listeners?
Have I made too many classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSpaceClicked);
function onSpaceClicked(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if ( event.target === emptySpace1 ) {
      // case 1...
    } else if ( event.target === emptySpace2 ) {
      // case 2...
    } else if ( event.target === emptySpace3 ) {
      // case 3...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm a little lost with my code (where do I have to put this one in my code). I'm gonna edit my post and put some of my code. If you could help me, it'll means a lot. thx !

Comment: I don't really like to downvote answers, but I do want to point out that this is not a good solution. If there are 100 `emptySpace` clips, your function would become unmanageable.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by checking either the `target` or `currentTarget` property of the `Event`:

```
// you should probably do this part in a loop of some sort.
emptySpace1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSpaceClicked);
emptySpace2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSpaceClicked);
emptySpace3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSpaceClicked);

function onSpaceClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var clickedSpace:MovieClip = evt.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    //... perform the actions you need to perform on the clickedSpace
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm a little lost with my code (where do I have to put this one in my code). I'm gonna edit my post and put some of my code. If you could help me, it'll means a lot. thx !

Comment: You'll want to add the event listeners wherever it is that the emptySpace clips are instantiated. It looks like you're already passing a reference to the clicked space in the `UseBox` constructor, you just need to make sure you use that reference to determine where to build the house.

Comment: Yes. If I click on the empty space a usebox appears. In this usebox I choose "buy" or "destroy". If I click "Buy", a window with differents buildings is appearing. When I click on the building that I want, the building must appear in the empty space.   You see, there's a lot of transition, this is why I don't know where to put the listeners.. I've tried everything but failed so far.